# как вставлять зачёркнутый (strikethrough) текст?

Tags: поддержка, faq, правки

иногда возникает желание (необходимость?) вставить зачёркнутый текст (или, например, зачеркнуть существующий при редактировании).

как это делать в сообщениях (вопросах и ответах), написано в подсказке при редактировании/создании сообщения:

> ```
> <strike>так</strike> или <s>так</s> или <del>так</del>
> ```
>
> <strike>так</strike> или <s>так</s> или <del>так</del>

но эти *html-теги* «не работают» ни в **комментариях**, ни в **[чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com)**.

Answer (score 15):

## в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com)

используйте синтаксис:

```
---зачёркнутый текст---
```

## в комментариях

(пока?) такой возможности нет (можно проголосовать здесь: [Comments should support the strike element](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31228/298597))

но есть «обходной» путь — воспользоваться [*unicode-ным* символом u+0336](http://unicode-table.com/ru/0336/). он «перечёркивает» предшествующий графический символ и состоит из двух байт: `\xcc\xb6`.

например, с помощью сайта, подобного этому: [Unicode strikethrough text tool](http://adamvarga.com/strike/).

или, если доступна, например, программа *sed*:

```
$ echo "текст" | sed 's/./&\xcc\xb6/g'
т̶е̶к̶с̶т̶
```

или *awk*:

```
$ echo "текст" | awk '$1=$1' FS= OFS="\xcc\xb6"
т̶е̶к̶с̶т
```

---

такое зачёркивание в некоторых случаях/браузерах/(с кириллицей) может отображаться не совсем корректно (или даже вообще не отображаться), но хоть как-то.

Comment: пример: з̶а̶ч̶ё̶р̶к̶н̶у̶т̶о̶е̶ слово.

Comment: Кстати, в обоих однострочниках в результате «те» не перечеркнуто. Ошибка? Или у нас отличается отображение? Я вот так вижу: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yH04o.png

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я про это и написал: «не совсем корректно». у меня отображается вот так: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eoKB9.png // а в комментариях, кстати, нормально выглядит: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SyMkn.png